# missing \right and Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--38

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I am trying to do put three vectors in a set for my math homework, but when i run it it shows me some errors and i have no idea how to work with it. Please help! 
Here is the code and its error

```
\begin{document}
1.  To find basis for the four fundemental subspaces, we need to get the
RREF of the matrix
A = $\begin{bmatrix}
               -3 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 \\
               0 & -1 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\
               1 & 2 & -3 & -4 & 2 \\
               -2 & 0 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
               0 & 2 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ = 
$\begin {bmatrix} 
             1 & 2 & -3 & -4 & 2 \\
             0 & 1 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
             0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
             0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
             0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$  = $\begin {bmatrix}
             1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
             0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} \\
             0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
             0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
             0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end {bmatrix}$\\
\\
now, we need to find the basis fo Col(A) and Row(A)\\
recall that a basis for Col(A) is the columns in the original matrix
with all the columns in RREF that has a leading one\\
thus, a basis for Col(A) is \\
\begin{equation}
Col(A) = \left \{$\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ , $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -3 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and the errors are shown

```
39 Missing \right. inserted.
<inserted text> 
            \right .
l.39 Col(A) = \left \{$
                   \begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}...

39 Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
\def 
l.39 Col(A) = \left \{$\begin{bmatrix}


14
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--38
```

Comment: Don't activate math mode `$`...`$` inside an `equation`. It's already in math mode.

Comment: You can't have `$ ... $` within `equation`. `equation` is a math mode environment, you're already in math mode. The first `$` of `$ ... $` will take you out of math mode, just when you need it, and the second `$` will put you back in math mode. But more generally, you should be in math mode for the entirety of your equations, not just for the matrices. If you're writing a single mathematical object/expression/equation, don't hop in and out of math mode, you need to stay in it

Comment: so i should take off all the $ in equation?

Comment: Certainly you should remove the `$`s you have within `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`

Comment: what about the missing \right?

Comment: nevermind, i removed all the $s inside and now the equation is working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Aren't you tired of getting errors and warnings due to the misplaced ``\\`` commands?

Answer (score 1):

You are already in mathmode inside the matrixes, so you don't need to start it again with `$`. That's where `Display math should end with $$.` comes from.

The error `Missing \right. inserted.` is because you seem to be leaving mathmode with the misplaced `$` in the matrix but you have started braces with `\left` and they are not closed with `\right` before the `$`.

This solved the issues:

```
\begin{document}
        1.  To find basis for the four fundemental subspaces, we need to get the
        RREF of the matrix\\
        $A = \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\
        1 & 2 & -3 & -4 & 2 \\
        -2 & 0 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
        0 & 2 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} = 
        \begin {bmatrix} 
        1 & 2 & -3 & -4 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}  = \begin {bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{4}{3} & \frac{4}{3} \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end {bmatrix}$\\
        \\
        now, we need to find the basis for $Col(A)$ and $Row(A)$\\
        recall that a basis for $Col(A)$ is the columns in the original matrix
        with all the columns in RREF that has a leading one\\
        thus, a basis for $Col(A)$ is \\
        \begin{equation}
            Col(A) = \left \{\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -3 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```